# Why are close votes not allowed on bounties?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why are close votes not allowed on bounties (at the least for duplicate questions)? Is this just by design or is there a specific reason behind this?

For example, take a look at this [bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379305/parse-blob-in-apex) [*there is/was an associated bounty at the time of posting this question*]. This [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/string-length-exceeds-maximum-6000000) seems to be a similar question and best possible answer for the bountied question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any official reasoning. I assume that it's because the purpose of a bounty is to invite further answers, and there's an assumption that a question with a bounty is likely also meeting the site's standards. That assumption may be wrong in some cases!

Comment: "That assumption may be wrong in some cases!" >> You are right about this. I'm sure that the questions that qualify for bounties might not fall under the category of lack of research, lack of relevant details, belongs to other site etc. But could be a duplicate in some cases. Anyways, thanks for the response.